# Customize generated schema names in SpringDoc

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc

I am aware that SpringDoc offers the use-fqn option nowadays. However that adds the full path with dots and $ characters. I am using the api-docs JSON to generate http clients, including all types. This generation is not working because of these characters being added to the name.

I would like a way to customize the naming strategy so that it's compatible with my client generation. Any ideas?

**Stack**

Spring boot 3.1.4
SpringDoc 2.3.0

Thanks in advance.